# What is an efficient algorithm to find all local minimums(maximums) in a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I want to find ALL local maximums in a `N*N` matrix, with a constraint that every 2 peaks found must be at least M cells away (in both directions). In other words, for very peak P found, local maximums within `(2M+1)*(2M+1)` sub-matrix around P are ignored, if that peak is lower than P.

By local maximum I mean the largest element in the `(2M+1)*(2M+1)` submatrix centered at the element.

For the naive method, the complexity is `O(N*N*M*M)`. Is there an efficient algorithm to achieve this?

This is a sample matrix for N=5 and M=1 (3*3 grid):

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) especially of your data as well.

Comment: What constitutes a peak? Any value that is greater than its neighbors? Greater by `1`, or by `0.1` or by `0.01`?

Comment: The problem seems under-determined. What would the output be for a constant matrix? Every point is a local max but then your additional constraint allows for multiple solutions, including solutions of different cardinalities.

Comment: @JohnColeman Good point. The existense of plateaus (neighbouring points with equal value) would be a complication. A clarification of whether such points exist and how they should be handled is necessary to implement a solution.

Comment: I edited the question. Local maximum is defined to be the largest element in the surrounding submatrix of width 2M+1. In case of ties(plateau), any peak can be selected. So, yes there are multiple possible solutions, finding any one is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your matrix appears to be something like an image, using image processing techniques appears to be the natural choice.

You could define peaks (local maxima or minima) as image regions with zero crossing of both local partial derivatives. If you want maxima look for negative curvature at these places, if you're looking for minima watch out for positive curvature (curvature -> second order derivative).

There are linear convolution operators available (and a whole lot of theory behind them), that produce the partial derivatives in x and y direction (e.g., [Sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), [Prewitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator)) and second order derivatives.

There's even algorithms for [blob detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) already, which appears to be related to your task (e.g., [Laplacian of Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection#The_Laplacian_of_Gaussian)).

If you are looking for speed, you might want to see if you can benefit of [linear separability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter), precomputation of filter kernels ([associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Properties)), or [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). Also note that this kind of tasks usually benefit hugely of parallelization. See if you can leverage more than one core, a GPU or an FPGA for some performance boost.

Comment: Yes, my matrix is for image processing. But I am not looking for edges (Sobel, Prewitt), I am looking for center of blob (same color area). Is there an algorithm for doing this?

Comment: @NeoWang You could have a look at the Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) again. It is used for blob detection. Didn't use it myself yet, but I'd expect you adjust the kernel size to the size of the blobs you want to find, and then apply some threshold in the output image. Then you could do some sort of agglomerative clustering on the candidate centers and produce a mean position as the actual blob center. Maybe there are better ways, though.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a floodfill approach (it's not actually floodfill, but floodfill was what I had in mind when I came up with it):

1. Find all minima. Put them in a sorted list/stack.
2. Pick (and remove) the first item from the list (lowest minimum).
3. If the element is marked as used, discard the item and go to 2.
4. Mark all elements inside the submatrix around the item as used.
5. Go to 2.

The algortihm ends when the list is empty.

Total cost: O(N*N + p * log p + p * M * M) where p is the number of minima.

Comment: Wouldn't you look at the M*M neighborhood already when you attempt to find all minima?

Comment: No, I was thinking that you just look at the closest neighbours. The first sweep will get ALL local minima, regardless of proximity to other minima. Looking at the closest neighbours instead of in a M*M neighbourhood is the key to making this algorithm cheaper than the naive method.

Comment: I guess you need some log term? It seems that your solution need to maintain a sorted list

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Thanks. Added the cost of sorting the list.

Comment: This can work when p is small enough. But in the worst case, p can be N*N/2.

Comment: I think this is worth exploring, if looking 1 cell around for local minima results in too large p value, maybe looking 2 cells around can greatly reduce the p value... A sweet spot can be found for a specific number distribution pattern.